# Error handling in synchronous model methods with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

So in my controller, I have something like this

```
Stuff.findByID(req.params.stuffID, function(err, stuff){
    if (err) return helper.handleErr(res, err);

    value = stuff.doThis(req.body);
    //handle possible error
    if (value instanceof Error) return helper.handleErr(res, err);

    stuff.doThatAsync(value, function(err){

        if (err) return helper.handleErr(res, err);

        stuff.save(function(err, stuff)){
             if (err) return helper.handleErr(res, err);
             return res.send(200).json(stuff);
        }
    });
}
```

And in my Model

```
stuffSchema.methods = { 
    doThis: function(info){
        if (info.blah doesn't meet various requirements){
            return new Error('Requirement not met');
        }
        //doStuff
        //...
        return computedValue;
    },
    doThatAsync: function(value, callback){
        if (value doesn't meet various requirements){
            return callback(new Error('Requirement not met'));
        }
        //do other stuff
        //...
        return callback(null, computedValue);
    }
}
```

Now this way of error handling for synchronous functions certainly works, but it doesn't seem nearly as elegant as handling errors in a callback, especially because the return value for my synchronous functions can often be the error or a desired return value (like in the above example) and it's a pain checking for whichever one it is.

The only other ways I though of doing this was using a try catch block in the controller and throwing an exception in the method, but that seems even more verbose. I could also make my synchronous functions async, but that seems very unnecessary. Any ideas? Or should I just keep it like this?

Comment: Your code looks async, not synchronous.  That means you can't use plain exceptions because you can't catch async exceptions at a higher level.  The simplest way to do this would be to convert all async operations to promises and then all your errors can propagate up to the highest level and you can handle it all in one `.catch(function(err) {...})` statement.  Async error propagation and auto exception handling is the #1 benefit of using promises for managing and controlling async operations.

Comment: I'm mainly asking about stuff.doThis, which is not an async function.